# Oracle: How to reference an alias with a space from a subquery in a comparison operation

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, alias

Is there a way to reference an alias that has a space in it in an Oracle SQL Query?  I haven't found it anywhere yet.  Normally I don't use spaces for naming database elements, so this is new ground for me.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT  t.id AS "Ticket ID",
(SELECT w.workgroup_title FROM workgroups w
WHERE w.operator_id = t.operator_id AND ROWNUM < 2) AS "Workgroup Title"
FROM tickets t
```

How would I use "Ticket ID" or "Workgroup Title" in a future comparison operation?  For example:

"Ticket ID" == 9
or
"Workgroup Title" == 'Workgroup #1'

I'm guessing there's an easy way to do this, just haven't found it yet.

Thanks!

PS This is for a legacy piece that was handed to me.  The aliases in the SQL tie dynamically into other various code, and all have spaces.  As a result, removing the spaces isn't a simple matter and I currently haven't been budgeted the time for it.  Otherwise, that's what I'd do.

*Edit for Clarification*
Using the example above, how would I do something like this where "Workgroup Title" always refers to the alias:

```
SELECT  t.id AS "Ticket ID",
(SELECT w.workgroup_title FROM workgroups w
WHERE w.operator_id = t.operator_id AND ROWNUM < 2) AS "Workgroup Title",
(SELECT s.support_tier_id FROM support_tiers s
WHERE s.workgroup_title == "Workgroup Title") AS "Support Tier ID"
FROM tickets t
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you have to enclose those names in double quotes:

```
-- SQL Example
SELECT "Just one" FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS "Just one" FROM dual
);
```

Output:

```
  Just one
----------
         1
```

```
-- PL/SQL Example
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (SELECT 1 AS "Just one" FROM dual)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_rec."Just one");
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output:

```
1
```

And a little curiosity:

```
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (SELECT COUNT(1) * 10 FROM dual)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_rec."COUNT(1)*10");
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This works.. and prints:

```
10
```

**Edit**

You can reference the aliased column elsewhere in your query, for example:

```
SELECT 'It is just one' FROM (
  SELECT "Just one" FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS "Just one" FROM dual
  ) t
WHERE t."Just one" = 1 -- prefixing with t. is not necessary in this particular example
);
```

Output:

```
It is just one
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question.  I know how to use the double quotes to establish the alias.  The question is how do I use that alias in a comparison operation somewhere else in the query.  I edited the question for more clarification.

Comment: @craignewkirk Please provide example where you would like to use it, in proper context. Anyway, you can reference that column by its alias wherever you want, **as long as the alias is known in the scope**.

Comment: @craignewkirk Please check my edited answer. If it is not what you were expecting, please provide an example of the problem you are facing.